# Azure pricing in case web server VM and database VM are in different region

Tags: azure

My WebServer VM is in different region and Database VM is in different region. For example, let's say WebServer VM is in Singapore, and Database VM is in US-West.

Now if I get a POST request from a user, which hits WebServer in Singapore region that inserts data into the database which is in US-West region, will this request be charged for outbound data transfer from webserver VM?

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the deployment as you described it would incur outbound data transfer charges.  You would see some cost from the web server (making the call to the database), and some cost from the database server (results going back to the web server).

Here is the pricing page for Azure that explains data transfer rates.  Notice that the rate varies by Zone.  In your example, it would be between Zone 1 and Zone 2.

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/data-transfers/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, all data outbound traffic is charged.

You also must take into consideration the latency caused by doing such a transaction, and the possible security issue in exposing your database on the Internet.